# exc-bad-access-code Error

Tags: ios, iphone

When I execute the code,
Following error occured.

Below is the error code.

Error : thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x30000

```
@interface PhotoEffectsVC : UIViewController
{
    void (^controllerImage) (UIImageView *);

}

- (IBAction)saveButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    controllerImage(self.imgView);
}


// In the view where i want to access the image

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIStoryboard *aUIStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    PhotoEffectsVC *photoEffectVC= [aUIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"getPhotosVC"];
    [photoEffectVC setControllerImage:^(UIImageView *imageName)
     {
         [self.imgView setImage:imageName.image ];

     }];


}
```

Comment: try with NSZombieEnabled you may get some idea about crash, to enable go to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics, also remember to disable it after you found issue.

Comment: Nothing happens, any other solutions ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the first line of the viewWillAppear method and then step along insuring that each pointer is not nil.